# SignalR and Memory Usage

Tags: signalr

So I have been playing around with the SignalR library which Scott Hanselman talks about briefly [Here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/AsynchronousScalableWebApplicationsWithRealtimePersistentLongrunningConnectionsWithSignalR.aspx). I have a use for an application that will basically be displaying real time data to a user(in a browser or a desktop app is still in debate). I am curious at what type of load, or memory usage would occur if SignalR ran on a 3-5 second loop and pushed data to the client. I would imagine this would eventually cause problems. If so, what is the alternative?

Comment: Why would that cause "problems"? 3-5 seconds is actually slow for SignalR as far as throughput. What type/size of data are we talking about? What have you tried so far?

Comment: What If I was to run a timer with an event handler that pushed small amounts of data to the client every 3-5 seconds? I have never done anything in the long running asynchronous manner like this, so I am unaware of any potential problems, memory leaks,etc.

Comment: Yes, that's nothing to worry about. Sending that little amount of data isn't concerning at all. In the current version of SignalR you'll run into problems when you start sending > 30K messages per second and in 1.0 alpha the 30K/s limitations will be gone.

Comment: Wow, in the presence of the SignalR godfather himself! Its a pleasure!